# How can i insert into table on the basis of a column value is same or not in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am inserting data into a table looks like this

```
|   num   | name     |  value |
----------------------------------
|    1    | name1    |   1    |
|    2    | name2    |   1    |
|    3    | name3    |   1    |
|    4    | name4    |   2    |
|    5    | name5    |   3    |
```

I wanted to insert with where clause like `insert into table (num, name, value) values(6,name,1) when (num and value together) not exist` in any row together

I tried to select first and insert on basis of that result but I think that is not the best way I want it in a single query

tried like: `select * from the table where name=$name and value= $value if I got result then not insert otherwise insert.` It was done with two queries but i don't want it.

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use a unique constraint to enforce uniqueness for `(num, value)`:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_num_value unique (num, value);
```

Then the database ensures that the integrity of the table -- that these values are unique.  You don't have to do it explicitly.

Note that if the unique constraint is violated, you get an error and the `insert` is aborted (along with other rows that might be inserted).  If you want to ignore the error instead, you can use `on conflict ignore`.

Comment: what if try to insert and violate there uniqueness. other rows which have  not unique value will be inserted or not and if there will be an error how can I get inserted id  i wanted a simple query without making uniqueness can you please tell me @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @bala . . . As pointed out in the answer, you can use `on conflict` to ignore errors.

Comment: there is a problem .... autoincrement incremented either it inserted or not. I mean on the conflict in not inserting but autoincrement increases @Gordon Linoff